Между какими определениями нужна запятая?
Большой прохладный железный покрашенный краской стол.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, между какими определениями требуется запятая?

В качестве варианта:
Большой, прохладный железный покрашенный краской стол.
Пояснение

Тема регулируется правилами Розенталя § 10. Однородные и неоднородные определения.

Между однородными определениями, не связанными союзами, ставится запятая.
 7) если за ОДИНОЧНЫМ определением следует определение, 
 выраженное ПРИЧАСТНЫМ ОБОРОТОМ: малоизвестные, 
 расположенные на отшибе курганы; древняя, почерневшая от 
 времени деревянная статуэтка; небольшое,твёрдый, плохо 
 выбритый подбородок (ср. при ДРУГОМ порядке слов: плохо 
 выбритый твёрдый подбородок).

 Ср. в языке художественной литературы: В сундуке я нашёл  
 пожелтевшую, написанную no-латыни  гетманскую грамоту 
 (Пауст.); Было как-то no-хорошему грустно в этом  
 маленьком, уже тронутом поздней осенью  саду (Горб.); 

 Но: чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна; заячий наполовину 
 потёртый воротник; большой собранный автором материал и т. 
 п. — первое определение относится К СОЧЕТАНИЮ второго 
 определения с существительным;


Большой, прохладный  — сближенные по восприятию неоднородные признаки.

Железный покрашенный краской стол — неоднородные определения; первое определение относится К СОЧЕТАНИЮ второго определения с существительным; сравнить чёрные появившиеся на скатерти пятна;
